# How to deploy using "ghpages+https" lektor method on windows? Getting the dollowing error:

Tags: windows, github, deployment, lektor

I've been relentlessly trying to solve the following problem while deploying a webpage for a friend to ghpages using [lektor](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/deployment/ghpages/). Yet i'm always getting an error similar to:

```
λ lektor deploy production
Deploying to production
  Build cache: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Lektor\Cache\builds\6edf4ce4c35ce53180e6c7f3b6a081ae
  Target: ghpages+https://user/user.github.io
  Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/user/repos/repo/temp/.deploytempswkcet/scratch/.git/
  Fetching origin
  fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master
  error: Could not fetch origin
  warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in about/index.html.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in blog/first-post/index.html.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in blog/index.html.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in index.html.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in projects/index.html.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
  error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Invalid argument
Done!
```

---

My configuration is currently set as follows:

```
[project]
name = repo

[servers.production]
target = ghpages+https://user/user.github.io
user = user
password = pass
```

---

Another attempt to solve this is typing the following:

```
lektor deplot --username user --password password production
```

rendering the following result:

```
Deploying to production
  Build cache: C:\Users\Aperez\AppData\Roaming\Lektor\Cache\builds\6edf4ce4c35ce53180e6c7f3b6a081ae
  Target: ghpages+https://johnmanruz/johnmanruz.github.io
  Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Aperez/repos/profejohnruz/temp/.deploytempcvsfya/scratch/.git/
  fatal: bad config line 12 in file .git/config
  fatal: bad config line 12 in file .git/config
  fatal: bad config line 12 in file .git/config
  fatal: bad config line 12 in file .git/config
Done!
```

If there is something wrong with my setup please let me know.

Comment: I did not see the fatal: bad config line 12 in file .git/config at first: what is in line 12?

Answer (score 1):

When looking at:

```
Fetching origin
  fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master
```

You could try and push first a commit from your local repo to your remote.
Then try again a `lektor deploy production`

Comment: The first error correctly got resolved, now the second error 'could not read username' is the only problem remaining.

Comment: @AperezC What version of Git are you using? When you type `git config -l`, do you see anything about a `credential.helper`?

Comment: No, not such a thing. I think lektor has an embedded git within it's code, because it works independently from my installed one, or at least it so appears.

Comment: @AperezC What is you try to change your origin remote of your local repo with ssh? `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git`

Comment: @AperezC maybe you have 2FA activiated for that GitHub user account? (https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/) (https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/176#issuecomment-175316598)

Comment: @AperezC also, just incase (as it is not idrectly related to authentication), make sure `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email` are properly valued.